# Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web missing Web menu (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I try to convert old ASP.NET `MVC 5 (349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21)` projects to new format with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

One main difference is the missing `Web` menu under `Project > Properties`. How could I configure these settings in the new format?

#### Old ASP.NET Project:

[image]

#### New `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` Project:

[image]

---

#### File Content of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` Project (`vbproj`)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\ptc\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OptionStrict>On</OptionStrict>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: At least some of those settings are under Debug now, but they look a little bit different.

Comment: I found it and I understand what you mean. Do you have experience why the output of `Publish` > `Folder` is so different? I miss a lot of folders and files (`bin`, `css`, `*.htm`, `*.css`, `*.aspx`)